# jQuery UI datepicker returning wrong date (intermitent bug)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having a problem using jQuery UI datepicker. I live in brazil, and our date format is dd/mm/yyyy, and that's the way that the datepicker shows the date on the screen. The problem is that, sometimes (yes, it's an intermitent bug), the datepicker.getDate() method returns the wrong date.

Here's an example:

User input (through datepicker on the screen): 04/02/2016
That date, in my country, means *February 4th*.

Sometimes, the system recognizes the date just the way it should, but sometimes it returns *April 2th* instead. In both cases, the function receives the same html content.

The html content is:

```
<input value="04/02/2016" class=" inicio hasDatepicker initialized" id="twf_anonymous_element_237" type="text"">
```

And here is the function which returns the date:

```
var getDatePickerValue = function(dataPickerElement){
        return dataPickerElement.datepicker('getDate');
}
```

I found that the bug happens here:

```
_getInst: function(target) {
    try {
        return $.data(target, PROP_NAME);
    }
    catch (err) {
        throw "Missing instance data for this datepicker";
    }
}
```

I've tried to go deeper on debug, but it reaches some jQuery UI functions that I simply can't understand.

Does anybody have a hint about it? If there's some relevant information that i forgot to add, please tell me.

Comment: Are you passing the dateFormat option while bootstrapping the datepicker?

Comment: @MrFrag yes, I am. `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'`